# ASP.Net C# create a cookie that expires at midnight

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know how to add days to a cookie but I am unsure how I would create a cookie that expires at midnight on the current day using ASP.Net and C#. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Who's midnight? Keep in mind the server and the user most likely run in different time zones. Servers are often configured to run in UTC.

Comment: You should name your cookie `Cinderella`.

Comment: @jp2code EPIC Comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should do it:

```
Response.Cookies["Cookie_SessionID"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is the server's midnight, which may not be the same as the user's midnight due to timezones.